# Pre-declaring a perl 2-D array reference

Tags: arrays, perl, memory, reference, declaration

I have a Perl program which will end up filling every index in a 5000 x 26 2-D array ref.

So consider:

```
my $aLarge2dArray;
for (my $i = 0; $i < 5000; $i++) {
    for (my $j = 0; $j < 26; $j++) {
        $aLarge2dArray->[$i][$j] = 'TRUE';
    };
};
```

I am running this on beast of a computer with TONS of memory, so am not worried about sparing the memory but I am keen on speed.

My gut feeling is that I would benefit from predeclaring $aLarge2dArray to make things faster and I have done so as follows:

```
my $aLarge2dArray;
$aLarge2dArray->[4999][25] = 0;
```

My questions:

1) is this the correct/best way to predeclare (and instantiate) the 2d array ref at initialisation?

2) is this going to make things any faster (remember memory is not an issue, I have plenty enough)?

Thanks for any answers/pointers.

Comment: You might not need to initialize it at all thanks to autovivification if you want to initialize it to false. e.g. `$aLarge2dArray->[$i][$j]` is functionally equivalent to `(($aLarge2dArray //= [] )->[$i] //= [])->[$j]`

Comment: Your advantage for pre-initializing may also be not as much as you imagine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll get only last cell in last array set to zero,

```
my $aLarge2dArray;
$aLarge2dArray->[10][5] = 0;

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $aLarge2dArray;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = [
      undef,
      undef,
      undef,
      undef,
      undef,
      undef,
      undef,
      undef,
      undef,
      undef,
      [
        undef,
        undef,
        undef,
        undef,
        undef,
        0
      ]
    ];
```

You might want to try this,

```
@$aLarge2dArray = map [ (0) x26 ], 0..4999;
```

Comment: Agreed, I would only set the "last" entry but my belief, perhaps incorrect, is that in order to do so, Perl would allocate the memory required for the full 2d array ref.  To put it another way: 1) would I have to fill every cell in my 2d array ref to "preallocate" the memory and 2) would this make things faster?

Comment: Every time a row other than the last one is accessed perl needs to dynamically resize it potentially as it's first not a arrayref and then potentially too short of an arrayref, which is not what he was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for you comments; I sense a consensus is that you would have to fill in all the cells with a dummy value to fully allocate the required memory.  The next (and perhaps more crucial) element of the question is would it make things faster?

Comment: @user3590005, I don't see why doing it sooner would be faster. At best, it might increase the odds of the variables being closer to each other in memory. If you actually did preallocate (using `$#a` or by assigning to the last element first), you'd save a couple of allocations, but it would be a rather small benefit.